# Compiling Java Maven project in Netbeans causing app to not run

Tags: java, maven, firebase, netbeans, firebase-realtime-database

Recently wrote a Maven Netbeans program that writes to firebase. It all works perfectly when I run it in the Netbeans IDE but when I build it and try to run it I get this error:

```
C:\Users\TOM\.m2\repository\com\FUJCode\climate2.0\1.0-SNAPSHOT>java -jar climate2.0-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder
    at Climate.main(Climate.java:94)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.

My code links to a json file here:

```
serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://controller-39c7e.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Climate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            serviceAccount.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Climate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

And I put the file itself here:

[image]

However I don't think this is the problem, I have added the dependencies in netbeans and like I said it runs in the IDE. Any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.FUJCode</groupId>
<artifactId>climate2.0</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<name>UsageMoniter</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>Climate</mainClass>

                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: We'd have to see the POM. Most of the time (except with a "fat jar" such as from Spring Boot), the standalone jar doesn't contain dependencies. It's quite clear from the file size that yours doesn't and will need extra classpath for them.

Comment: added the pom, please see the edit.

Comment: @constantvigilance how are you running the program without *Netbeans IDE*?

Comment: in the cmd i put "java -jar climate2.0-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"